# how to find the integer values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, fractions, integers

Let $N = \frac{3k−8}{k+4}$,

where $k$ is an integer.

List all positive values of k for which $N$ is an integer.

Do this using algebra, without using a calculator.

Also do not do this by enumeration, i.e., plugging in $k = 1, 2, ...$ and
checking the value of $N$.

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: I was confused at how to start the question as I didn't get an idea of how would one get an answer in integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint:
$$\frac{3k-8}{k+4}=\frac{3k+12-20}{k+4}=3-\frac{20}{k+4},$$
which says that $20$ is divisible by $k+4$.

Id est, $$k+4\in\{5,10,20\}$$ because $k>0$